# How do I write basic "Hello World" java script plugin in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've read Cordova's tutorials, but I'm not sure they've given me enough information.

EDITED TO SHOW UPDATED CODE:

Let me show you my code:

From the config.xml:

```
<plugin name="someMethod" value="MyPluginClass" />
```

Now for the Plugin.h:

```
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface MyPluginClass : CDVPlugin

- (void)someMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

Now for the Plugin.m:

```
#import "Plugin.h"

@implementation MyPluginClass

- (void)someMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command
{
    NSLog(@"YOU ARE READING THIS NATIVELY FROM A PLUGIN");
}

@end
```

The very first html page that gets displayed is called "index.html"

I just want a blank html page which simply runs a script that calls the cordova.exec() function. My attempts in doing so have failed. I don't know whether there's something I've done wrong with my script or something I've done wrong elsewhere but here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cordova Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
        //
        // At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-2.3.0.js has not.
        // When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
        // it will call the event `deviceready`.
        //
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Now safe to use the Cordova API
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
                                      cordova.exec(null,null,"MyPluginClass","someMethod",[]);
                                      }, false);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error logs:

2013-01-17 11:36:31.782 CCT[1293:907] ERROR: Plugin 'MyPluginClass' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.

2013-01-17 11:36:31.787 CCT[1293:907] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","MyPluginClass","someMethod",[]]

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but is that your entire index.html? You'll need to load cordova.js as well, and wait for deviceready to fire...

Comment: No, sorry. I thought I'd simplify my post it a bit. I'm using the default Phonegap index.html page with my added script. I've updated this page with the full html (minus the comment at the top) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't make any calls to cordova until the [deviceready](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) event fires. Do:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    cordova.exec(null,null,"MyPluginClass","someMethod",[]);
 }, false);
```

**Edit:**

For the example call listed above, you'd need an Objective-C class that looks like:

```
@interface MyPluginClass : CDVPlugin

- (void)someMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

Note the name of the class, and name of the method, which match the call to `cordova.exec`

**Another Edit:**

Your `config.xml` should look like the following:

`<plugin name="MyPluginClass" value="MyPluginClass" />`

(these don't necessarily have to be the same, but `name` should match the reference in the third argument of the javascript call, and `value` should match the name of your Objective-C class.

For full documentation on developing a plugin for iOS, check out the [guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS)

Comment: Thanks for the response and your link to that documentation. However, using the html on that site, I get the following error: "ERROR: Method ':' not defined in Plugin 'test'
-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","test","",[]]" What is wrong here?

Comment: Edited the answer to provide more detail, hope it helps!

Comment: I feel we're getting close, but I'm still not quite there. Thank you for bearing with my ignorance here. I've updated my code to be more clear, but I'm still getting errors. I've edited my original post to have all of my updated code. Notice the error log and my config.xml. It looks correct and I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: THAT WORKED. But I have another question: If I would like to add multiple methods to this class, how would I declare those methods in the config.xml? Do I really have to have a new plugin class every time I need something from my native code? Or do I just keep the config.xml as is and have exec change its parameters?

Comment: You can have multiple methods in your Plugin - you don't need to declare them in config.xml - you only need to map to the plugin once in config.xml (for the class). In your javascript, change `someMethod` to your new method, and in your plugin class, add the new method.