# cannot able to create a phonegap ios plugin in cordova 2.4

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am try to instal [this](https://github.com/jfpsf/flurry-phonegap-plugin)
phonegap ios plugin, but it gives an error  "ERROR: Plugin '' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml." in my config.xml

```
 <plugin name="Flurry" value="FlurryPhoneGapPlugin" />
```

and in plugin.js

```
cordova.exec(successCallback, successCallback, 'Flurry', 'startSession', [key]);
```

, and plugin .h  file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface FlurryPhoneGapPlugin : CDVPlugin
```

FlurryPhoneGapPlugin.m file

```
 #import "FlurryPhoneGapPlugin.h"
   #import <Cordova/CDV.h>

   @implementation FlurryPhoneGapPlugin
```

the service name and action name , Objective c Classname are same in config.xml,

after getting this error i try to create my own simple echo plugin according to [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface FlurryPhoneGapPlugin : CDVPlugin


 - (void)myMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
@end
```

and .m file

```
#import "FlurryPhoneGapPlugin.h"
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@implementation FlurryPhoneGapPlugin



(void)myMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{


  NSLog(@"hi");
  CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
  NSString* echo = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

  if (echo != nil && [echo length] > 0) {
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:echo];
  } else {
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
  }

  [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];


}
@end
```

my plugin.js file

```
cordova.exec(success, error , 'Flurry', 'myMethod', ['19']);
```

my  config.xml

```
    <plugin name="Flurry" value="FlurryPhoneGapPlugin" />
```

but this time also i got error

```
    2013-03-19 10:30:46.349 artra[15560:707] ERROR: Plugin 'Flurry' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2013-03-19 10:30:46.354 artra[15560:707] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  null,
  "",
  "success",
  [
    "error",
    "Flurry",
    "myMethod",
    [
      "19"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368597/how-do-i-write-basic-hello-world-java-script-plugin-in-phonegap

Comment: #import <Cordova/JSONKit.h>

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode make sure your config.xml is not 'grey'. 
If the file is grey it means it has not yet been saved.
Failing that try a clean.

Do let us know if you managed to resolve your problem :)